# How to generate html file and upload it to sharepoint 2007 document library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

We are using sharepoint 2007
We have one requirement in which We have one custom document upload page for document library.
While uploading we are taking some other inputs from user.
We want to upload file and at that time generate one HTML file dynamically and upload it also to the Document library.

Any help on this please.

Thanks in advance,
Rushikesh

Comment: What is your question? Program a custom `upload.aspx`, put some fields on it and logic to generate HTML upon saving...

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with an event receiver on the document library. Perhaps one for `ItemAdded` and `ItemUpdated`.

Here is a reference: [SPItemEventReceiver.ItemUpdated Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemupdated%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

In the event receivers you could create / modify the HTML file.

Comment: If the OP wants to program a custom upload page (*"some other inputs"*), all logic could be contained within that page instead of creating an event receiver.